GUI tool that highlights text files based on custom semantics
I frequently find myself loading and parsing text files. Debugging a parser sometimes gets a little complex. I was wondering if there was some gui or part of some editor that does highlighting. For example, if I loaded up,
To be, or not to be, that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer

and the label file,
1:1-1:20 question
2:1-2:20 question
1:30-1:33 the
2:24-2:27 the

…it would simply highlight the words in the first one in same arbitrary colour based on the label.
Further explanation: 1:1-1:30 is "line 1, code-point 1 to line 1, code point 20" which—looking at the text—is "To be, or not to be". I would want that highlighted in the same colour as "Whether 'tis nobler" because they are the disjoint-set "question", similarly with "the".

Does it have to use that specific syntax? What exactly does it mean, e.g. why is there 1:1 with the given example?

It does not have to use that syntax at all—it is just a very trivial example that I made up off the top of my head. The second part doesn't even need to be a file. I would like it to be documented, though, so I could automate highlighting syntax from my command-line parser.

Sounds easy enough to implement yourself. If you can implement a parser, you can probably also implement that highlighting, e.g. using a RichTextBox.
